# Tricky try-catch java code

Tags: java

```
public class Strange1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Missing m = new Missing();
    } catch (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ex) {
      System.out.println("Got it!");
    }
  }
}

public class Strange2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Missing m;
    try {
      m = new Missing();
    } catch (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ex) {
      System.out.println("Got it!");
    }
  }
}

class Missing {
  Missing() { }
}
```

If you run Strange1 and Strange2 after deleting `Missing.class`, Strange1 will throw `NoClassDefFoundError;` but Strange2 will print Got it！

Can anyone explain that? Thanks.

updated:

java bytecode for `Strange1` :

```
     0  new info.liuxuan.test.Missing [16]
     3  dup
     4  invokespecial info.liuxuan.test.Missing() [18]
     7  astore_1 [m]
     8  goto 20
    11  astore_1 [ex]
    12  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [19]
    15  ldc <String "Got it!"> [25]
    17  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [27]
    20  return
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 8] -> 11 when : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 14]
        [pc: 11, line: 15]
        [pc: 12, line: 16]
        [pc: 20, line: 18]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 21] local: args index: 0 type: java.lang.String[]
        [pc: 8, pc: 11] local: m index: 1 type: info.liuxuan.test.Missing
        [pc: 12, pc: 20] local: ex index: 1 type: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

java bytecode for `Strange2` :

```
     0  new info.liuxuan.test.Missing [16]
     3  dup
     4  invokespecial info.liuxuan.test.Missing() [18]
     7  astore_1 [m]
     8  goto 20
    11  astore_2 [ex]
    12  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [19]
    15  ldc <String "Got it!"> [25]
    17  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [27]
    20  return
      Exception Table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 8] -> 11 when : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 15]
        [pc: 11, line: 16]
        [pc: 12, line: 17]
        [pc: 20, line: 19]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 21] local: args index: 0 type: java.lang.String[]
        [pc: 8, pc: 11] local: m index: 1 type: info.liuxuan.test.Missing
        [pc: 12, pc: 20] local: ex index: 2 type: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

There is only one place is different:

```
11  astore_1 [ex]
```

and

```
11  astore_2 [ex]
```

updated again:

Everyone can try it in eclipse.

Comment: look at the generated bytecode to see the difference.

Comment: They both print "Got it!" for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete"?  It shouldn't even compile if it isn't present at compile time.  Please edit your question to be more specific.  Also, the title doesn't mean anything with respect to the question - can you edit it also to be more specific?

Comment: @Merlyn: He means delete the class file, not the source file.  In other words, after compilation (`javac`) but before running (`java`).

Comment: +1 both for this great question and for listening to advice:)

Comment: Maybe it depends on the version of Java or the compiler options, but I too got "Got it!" for both files.

Comment: @Mark Peters: thank you for your reminding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to saying anything, i doub't this code won't even compile. because when compiler cannot find a class (Since its deleted). may be you are getting an error when trying to compile it using `javac` command. if thats the case its pretty normal and in no way its weird.

and let me add an another point.. check your imports, to contain **Missing class**. if it is there then remove it. and tell us whats happening.

Comment: I would expect what you said to be true, but it looks like he's experience the opposite behavior (everything in the comments non-withstanding) - the variable declaration one does get caught.

Answer (score 1):

I created two java files. Strange1.java contained classes Strange1 and Missing. Strange2.java contained Strange2 class. I removed Missing.class.
I got "Got it!" from both.

Please see the following details:

```
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ gedit Strange1.java
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ gedit Strange2.java
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ javac Strange1.java 
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ javac Strange2.java 
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ java Strange1
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ java Strange2
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ rm Missing.class
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ java Strange1
Got it!
manohar@manohar-natty:~$ java Strange2
Got it!
```

I executed it in Ubuntu 11.04 linux machine.

So it might be the java's version that you are using.

Comment: I tried it in eclipse, so you may have a try in eclipse. But what I got in command is both NoClassDefFoundError. I've tried both JDK 1.5.0_06 and 1.6.0_23.

Comment: I too tried it in Eclipse Helios too and I got "Got it!" as said earlier.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError is thrown whenever the first reference(declaring or creating an instance) to the missing class is made. Now, throwing an error or catching it depends on whether you use try-catch block for your first reference or not.

Answer (score 0):

## Output

The behavior of both programs depends on the version of `javac` used to compile them and not the version of `java` used to run the compiled classes. However, it's easier to use the same `javac` and `java` versions.

We'll be using J2SE 5.0 and Java SE 6 because those are the earliest versions where the programs' behavior deviates.

With `build 1.5.0_22-b03`:

```
$ jdk1.5.0_22/bin/javac {Strange1,Strange2,Missing}.java
$ rm Missing.class

$ jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java Strange1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Missing

$ jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java Strange2
Got it!

$ jdk1.5.0_22/bin/javap -c Strange1
Compiled from "Strange1.java"
public class Strange1 extends java.lang.Object{
public Strange1();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class Missing
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method Missing."<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   goto    20
   11:  astore_1
   12:  getstatic       #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   15:  ldc     #6; //String Got it!
   17:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   20:  return
  Exception table:
   from   to  target type
     0     8    11   Class java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError


}

Compiled from "Strange2.java"
public class Strange2 extends java.lang.Object{
public Strange2();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class Missing
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method Missing."<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   goto    20
   11:  astore_2
   12:  getstatic       #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   15:  ldc     #6; //String Got it!
   17:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   20:  return
  Exception table:
   from   to  target type
     0     8    11   Class java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError


}
```

With `build 1.6.0_45-b06`:

```
$ jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac {Strange1,Strange2,Missing}.java
$ rm Missing.class

$ jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java Strange1
Got it!

$ jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java Strange2
Got it!

$ jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javap -c Strange1
<Same output as the corresponding command for J2SE 5.0>

$ jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javap -c Strange2
<Same output as the corresponding command for J2SE 5.0>
```

## Analysis

The bytecode of `Strange1` and `Strange2` is nearly identical, except for the mapping of the catch parameter `ex` to a VM local variable. `Strange1` stores it in VM variable 1, i.e., `11: astore_1`. `Strange2` stores it in VM variable 2, i.e., `11: astore_2`.

In both classes, the local variable `m` is stored in VM variable 1. Both versions of `main` also have a merge point where the flow of control from two different code paths converge. The merge point is `20:  return`. It can be reached either by completing the `try` block normally, i.e., `8:   goto    20`, or by completing the `catch` block and falling through from instruction 17.

The existence of the merge point causes an exception during the verification of class `Strange1`, but not class `Strange2` in J2SE 5.0.

[JLS, Java SE 6 Edition - Chapter 12 - Execution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/execution.html) specifies activities that occur during execution of a program:

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by loading a specified class and then invoking the method main in this specified class. Section §12.1 outlines the loading, linking, and initialization steps involved in executing main, as an introduction to the concepts in this chapter. Further sections specify the details of loading (§12.2), linking (§12.3), and initialization (§12.4).

[JLS, Java SE 6 Edition - Section 12.3 - Linking of Classes and Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/execution.html#12.3) specifies that the first activity that is involved in linking is verification.

[JVMS, Java SE 7 Edition - Section 4.10 - Verification of class Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10) specifies the two strategies that a VM may use for verification:

> There are two strategies that Java Virtual Machine implementations may
> use for verification:
>
> - Verification by type checking must be used to verify class files whose version number is greater than or equal to 50.0.
> - Verification by type inference must be supported by all Java Virtual Machine implementations, except those conforming to the Java
>   ME CLDC and Java Card profiles, in order to verify class files whose
>   version number is less than 50.0.
>
> Verification on Java Virtual Machine implementations supporting the Java ME CLDC and Java Card profiles is governed by their
> respective specifications.

([Verification by type checking was added to JVMS, Second Edition for Java SE 6](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr924/index2.html), and JVMS, Java SE 7 Edition incorporates these changes in a more accessible way.)

### Verification by type inference (for class files whose version number is less than 50.0, i.e., Java SE 6)

> To merge two local variable array states, corresponding pairs of local
> variables are compared. If the two types are not identical, then
> unless both contain reference values, the verifier records that the
> local variable contains an unusable value. If both of the pair of
> local variables contain reference values, the merged state contains a
> reference to an instance of the first common superclass of the two
> types.
> [JVMS, Second Edition - Section 4.9.2 - The Bytecode Verifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/ClassFile.doc.html#9801)

When instruction 20 is reached from instruction 8 in `Strange1.main`, VM variable 1 contains an instance of the class `Missing`. When reached from instruction 17, it contains an instance of the class `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Because `Missing.class` has been deleted, the verifier can't load it to determine the first common superclass, and throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Note that there is no stack trace printed for the uncaught exception because it's thrown during verification, before class initialization and long before `main` begins execution.

### Verification by type checking (for class files whose version number is greater than or equal to 50.0, i.e., Java SE 6)

(I've tried my best to follow the rules as precisely as possible. However, they are complex, dense and new to me. Hence, if you spot any mistakes, please feel free to correct them. If you could summarize the rules, that'd be great too.)

Because of the `StackMapTable` attribute, it's not necessary for the verifier to compute the first common superclass to merge the two VM variable 1's types as in the other strategy. Also, there's no need to actually load classes `Missing`, `NoClassDefFoundError`, or any other classes other than `Strange1` for verification thanks to the constant pool and how the rules work.

Hence, there are no exceptions during verification. If you modify the `catch` block to print out the exception's stack trace, you'll see that the exception is thrown during the execution of `Strange1.main` with a proper stack trace:

```
# Modify Strange1.main's catch block to print out the exception's stack trace
$ jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac {Strange1,Missing}.java
$ rm Missing.class

$ jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java Strange1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Missing
        at Strange1.main(Strange1.java:4)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Missing
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 1 more
Got it!
```

The `StackMapTable` of `Strange1`:

```
$ jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javap -verbose Strange1 | tail
   line 10: 20

  StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
   frame_type = 75 /* same_locals_1_stack_item */
     stack = [ class java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError ]
   frame_type = 8 /* same */


}
```

Let's go through the rules (as the verifier) to prove that `Strange1.main` is type safe. Each instruction of `Strange1.main` is verified to be type safe and satisfies all applicable (exception) handlers:

```prolog
methodWithCodeIsTypeSafe(Strange1Class, MainMethod) :-
    parseCodeAttribute(Strange1Class, MainMethod, FrameSize, MaxStack,
                       ParsedCode, Handlers, StackMap),
    mergeStackMapAndCode(StackMap, ParsedCode, MergedCode),
    methodInitialStackFrame(Strange1Class, MainMethod, FrameSize, StackFrame, ReturnType),
    Environment = environment(Strange1Class, MainMethod, ReturnType, MergedCode,
                              MaxStack, Handlers),
    handlersAreLegal(Environment),
    mergedCodeIsTypeSafe(Environment, MergedCode, StackFrame).
    
mergedCodeIsTypeSafe(Environment, [instruction(Offset, Parse) | MoreCode],
                     frame(Locals, OperandStack, Flags)) :-
    instructionIsTypeSafe(Parse, Environment, Offset,
                          frame(Locals, OperandStack, Flags),
                          NextStackFrame, ExceptionStackFrame),
    instructionSatisfiesHandlers(Environment, Offset, ExceptionStackFrame),
    mergedCodeIsTypeSafe(Environment, MoreCode, NextStackFrame).
    
mergedCodeIsTypeSafe(Environment, [stackMap(Offset, MapFrame) | MoreCode],
                     afterGoto) :-
    mergedCodeIsTypeSafe(Environment, MoreCode, MapFrame).
    
instructionSatisfiesHandlers(Environment, Offset, ExceptionStackFrame) :-
    exceptionHandlers(Environment, Handlers),
    sublist(isApplicableHandler(Offset), Handlers, ApplicableHandlers),
    checklist(instructionSatisfiesHandler(Environment, ExceptionStackFrame),
              ApplicableHandlers).

instructionSatisfiesHandler(Environment, StackFrame, Handler) :-
    ... 
    /* The stack consists of just the exception. */
    StackFrame = frame(Locals, _, Flags),
    ExcStackFrame = frame(Locals, [ ExceptionClass ], Flags),
    operandStackHasLegalLength(Environment, ExcStackFrame),
    targetIsTypeSafe(Environment, ExcStackFrame, Target).
    
targetIsTypeSafe(Environment, StackFrame, Target) :-
    offsetStackFrame(Environment, Target, Frame),
    frameIsAssignable(StackFrame, Frame).
```

Instructions 0-7 are type safe because `instructionIsTypeSafe` is `true` and `frameIsAssignable(Environment, frame(Locals, [ NoClassDefFoundErrorClass ], Flags), frame(Locals, [ NoClassDefFoundErrorClass ], Flags))` is `true` for each of them thanks to the first stack map frame for the (exception) handler target at instruction 19 (= 75 - 64):

```
frame_type = 75 /* same_locals_1_stack_item */
     stack = [ class java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError ]
```

Instructions 12-17 are type safe thanks to the constant pool and the corresponding rules which are not listed (because they don't make up of the `StackMapTable` attribute).

There are 3 instructions left to prove their type-safety:

- `8:   goto    20` is type safe thanks to the second stack map frame for the target at instruction 20 (= 75 - 64 + 8 + 1 = 19 + 8 + 1), instructing the verifier that the stack frame there is the same as the previous stack frame at instruction 8:

```
frame_type = 8 /* same */
```

```prolog
instructionIsTypeSafe(goto(Target), Environment, _Offset, StackFrame,
                      afterGoto, ExceptionStackFrame) :-
    targetIsTypeSafe(Environment, StackFrame, Target),
    exceptionStackFrame(StackFrame, ExceptionStackFrame).
```

- `11:  astore_1` is type safe because the store is type safe, because it can pop a `NoClassDefFoundError` that is a subtype of `reference` off the stack (thanks to the first stack map frame again), and then legally assign that type to the local variable 1, i.e., `Locals = [arrayOf(String), class(Missing, Lm)] -> NewLocals = [arrayOf(String), class(NoClassDefFoundError, Ln)]`.

```
An astore instruction with operand Index is type safe and yields an outgoing type state NextStackFrame, if a store instruction with operand Index and type reference is type safe and yields an outgoing type state NextStackFrame. 

instructionIsTypeSafe(astore(Index), Environment, _Offset, StackFrame,
                      NextStackFrame, ExceptionStackFrame) :- 
    storeIsTypeSafe(Environment, Index, reference, StackFrame, NextStackFrame),
    exceptionStackFrame(StackFrame, ExceptionStackFrame).

More precisely, the store is type safe if one can pop a type ActualType that "matches" Type (that is, is a subtype of Type) off the operand stack (§4.10.1.4), and then legally assign that type the local variable LIndex.

storeIsTypeSafe(_Environment, Index, Type,
                frame(Locals, OperandStack, Flags),
                frame(NextLocals, NextOperandStack, Flags)) :-
    popMatchingType(OperandStack, Type, NextOperandStack, ActualType),
    modifyLocalVariable(Index, ActualType, Locals, NextLocals).
```

- `20:  return` is type safe because `Strange1.main` declares a `void` return type, and the enclosing method is not an `<init>` method:

```
A return instruction is type safe if the enclosing method declares a void return type, and either:

  - The enclosing method is not an <init> method, or

  - this has already been completely initialized at the point where the instruction occurs.

instructionIsTypeSafe(return, Environment, _Offset, StackFrame,
                      afterGoto, ExceptionStackFrame) :- 
    thisMethodReturnType(Environment, void),
    StackFrame = frame(_Locals, _OperandStack, Flags),
    notMember(flagThisUninit, Flags),
    exceptionStackFrame(StackFrame, ExceptionStackFrame).
```

Comment: These programs are part of Puzzle 44 - Cutting Class in Joshua Bloch, Neal Gafter, 2009, 6th printing, Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases, Addison-Wesley, Crawfordsville, Indiana.